# Force validation of every cell of a Datagrid when button is pressed

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, validation

How can I force all the cells to validate in a datagrid in a c# winform application when a ToolStripButton is pressed?

I have individual cell validation working when the user edits the cell it calls my cell validating event.  But, I can't get it to validate all cells when a button is pressed.  I tried calling Validate() but it's not calling the CellValidating function on every cell

Comment: Did you try putting the validate() in a while loop and looping through each cell? And post the code for the validate() function please.

Comment: @JonF - CellValidating doesn't get called until you change the CurrentCell, see the solution (a little bit dirty but hey it works) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422865/can-i-make-datagridview-endedit-trigger-the-cellvalidating-event

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Trigger Datagridview.cellValidating manually?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915735/how-to-trigger-datagridview-cellvalidating-manually)

Comment: You can try `row.BindingGroup.ValidateWithoutUpdate()` https://stackoverflow.com/a/42476772/2122718